# ASP.NET Core MVC - add a DB bound checkbox to Create.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm working with ASP.NET Core MVC and trying to add a list of checkboxes that are bound to a list of objects from the database, and I'm getting lost. In my `Create.cshtml` page, the route is null, obviously, so how do I populate the `AllDonors` property with a list of all of my donors from the database, and show them in a list of checkboxes?

Route class:

```
public class Route : ModelBase
{
    [Key]
    public int RouteID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Frequency")]
    public int FrequencyID { get; set; }
    public virtual Frequency Frequency { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "DayOfWeek")]
    public int DayOfWeekID { get; set; }
    public virtual DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "TimeOfDay")]
    public int TimeOfDayID { get; set; }
    public virtual TimeOfDay TimeOfDay { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Donors")]
    public int DonorID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RouteOrg> RouteOrgDonors { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Agency")]
    public int AgencyID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RouteOrg> RouteOrgAgencies { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Organization> AllDonors { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Organization> AllAgencies { get; set; }
}
```

RouteController - Index method:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var myDatabaseContext = _context.Route
            .Include(s => s.RouteOrgDonors)
            .Include(s => s.RouteOrgAgencies)
            .Include(s => s.AllDonors)
            .Include(s => s.AllAgencies)
            .Include(s => s.DayOfWeek)
            .Include(s => s.Frequency)
            .Include(s => s.TimeOfDay);

        return View(await myDatabaseContext.ToListAsync());
    }
```

`Create.cshtml` view markup:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DonorID" class="control-label"></label>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.AllDonors.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                            name="SelectedFruits"
                            value="Model.AllDonors[i].OrgID"
                            @*@if (Model.RouteOrgDonors.Contains(item)) { <text> checked </text> }*@ />
                    Model.AllDonors[i].Name
                    </label>
            </div>
        }
        @*<select asp-for="DonorID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DonorID"></select>*@
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `Count()` method,you need to use `IList` instead of `IEnumerable` for your `AllDonors` property.

```
public IList<Organization> AllDonors { get; set; }
```

Create Action(Get):

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {

        var Route = new Route();
        Route.AllDonors = _context.Organizations.ToList();//populate AllDonors

        return View(Route);
    }
```

Create View:

```
@model Demo.Models.Route
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="DonorID" class="control-label"></label>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.AllDonors.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"
                       name="SelectedFruits"
                       value="@Model.AllDonors[i].OrgID" />
                @Model.AllDonors[i].Name
            </label>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, If I understand your problem correctly..

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.AllDonors.Count; i++)
        {
var isChecked= = "";
if (Model.RouteOrgDonors.Contains(item)){

isChecked = "checked"
<input type="hidden" name="AllDonors[i].Id" 
    value="@AllDonors[i].Id"/>
    }
else {
 isChecked = "";
}    

<div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"                    
                name="SelectedFruits"
                    value="Model.AllDonors[i].OrgID" />
                    Model.AllDonors[i].Name
                   @isChecked
         </label>
</div>       
        }
```